# Runtime Error MESSAGE_TYPE_X when using SAP GUI on Ipad mini (IOS)

Tags: ios, sap-gui

In my company we´ve installed the app GuiXT Liquid UI on Ipad mini to access our SAP Systems.

The login works fine and we can open transactions (those which were delivered by SAP GUI and also self-written), but as soon as we want to change variant, display a list or anything else, a Runtime Error occurs.
While opening the same transactions with the “normal” GUI on Windows PC, everything works well.

Following information I get from the error message:

```
Runtime Errors         MESSAGE_TYPE_X


Error analysis
Short text of error message:
Control Frame Work : Error in data stream <DATAMANAGER><TABLES><DATACHAN
GES HANDLE="2"><IT I; current tag PROPERTY,

Long text of error message:
Technical information about the message:
Message class....... "CNDP"
Number.............. 008
Variable 1.......... "<DATAMANAGER><TABLES><DATACHANGES HANDLE="2"><IT I"
Variable 2.......... "PROPERTY"
Variable 3.......... " "
Variable 4.......... " "

Information on where terminated
     Termination occurred in the ABAP program "CL_GUI_DATAMANAGER============CP" -
      in "TRACE_XML".
     The main program was "RAZUGA_ALV01 ".

 In the source code you have the termination point in line 2136
 of the (Include) program "CL_GUI_DATAMANAGER============CL".
```

[image: source code extract]

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question and I hope you found a solution.
I stumbled upon it while searching for help on a similar (but not exactly the same) error.

I found this note which doesn't apply to my system/error, but might apply to yours, so I'll leave it here for reference:

[2318244](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2318244) - Shortdump occurs in /IDXGC/PDOCMON01 when click some Process Step No. to display step additional data

Regards,

tao